# How to change color of CNContactPickerViewController searchBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, cncontactpicker

I start a CNContactPickerViewController from a viewcontroller, but how can I change the textcolor of the searchbar inside it. The navigationbar is dark blue, in iOS11 the default searchbartext is black.

Comment: is this a bug or new in iOS11

Comment: Since iOS 11 is out now, I think this is new in iOS11, depending on the tintcolor of your app.

Comment: I didn't find a way to change the text color of searchbar it stays black but I managed to change the background color instead 

[[UISearchBar appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

Comment: The correct solution for me was @MohamedElkassas's comment, `[[UISearchBar appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];`.
This bug is only present in iOS 11, @RBN.

Answer (score 3):

I updated the way to fix in swift
Before you present CNContactPickerViewController, you should set background color of UISearchBar

```
            UISearchBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        let cancelButtonAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: ColorConstant.baseColorGray]
        UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf:
         [UISearchBar.self]).setTitleTextAttributes(cancelButtonAttributes, for: .normal)
```