# CNContactPickerViewController is affected by UINavigationBar.Appearance in ios 11

Tags: ios11

Is this by design ?

The app, I am working on has a black background navigation bar and white text, set using UINavigationBar.Appearance BarStyle / BarTintColor / TintColor

On iOS 10 all is good: when a CNContactPickerViewController is presented, its ui has a white background. On ios 11 it has a black navigation bar. The problem is the UISearchBar: it displays black text over a black background....

Comment: It seems CNContactPickerViewController got left behind by Apple a long time ago and no one has cared to update it for the last several iOS versions, unfortunately.

Comment: It is an ios 9 thing, not so old. On ios 10 it works fine.

Comment: CNContactPickerViewController in general has been flawed since the beginning. The Search bar is unhideable and also unusable when picking multiple contacts, so this has needed fixing since iOS 9, but has been ignored by Apple for three iOS's.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change color of CNContactPickerViewController searchBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46162120/how-to-change-color-of-cncontactpickerviewcontroller-searchbar)